# Setting up Platform targets/COM and BadImageFormatException

Tags: c#, platform

I have a C# Project which contains 5 class libraries and 1 Windows Forms Application and I am having some trouble setting up the Platform/Build targets. The problem is one of my classes is purely for connecting to an Oracle database, and requires; Oracle.DataAccess. Another class prints out items with barcodes, and that requires a barcode library (fontwarecode128).

So at the moment, my project is setup like this;

```
Configuration Manager -> Any CPU
WPF Class Platform Target -> Any CPU
Oracle Class -> Any CPU
Printing Class -> x86
Other Classes -> Any CPU
```

The function that uses the Oracle.DataAccess.dll works fine, but the printing function does not and throws a System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly error.

I'm pretty new to these sort of errors so if anyone can shed some information and help me resolve these issues it would be greatly appreciated. Feel free to ask for more information. Thanks

Comment: Only the Platform Target setting in your EXE project matters.  That's the one that starts running first and nails down the bitness of the process.  Mixing is not possible.  You must change it to x86 because you have a dependency on that 32-bit barcode library.  Beware that you'll probably next have a problem with the Oracle data provider, you'll have to switch over to the 32-bit version for it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @HansPassant Your right when I change it to x86 the Oracle data provider does throw errors. To clarify; I should change all of the projects Platform Target to x86 [which should sort the printing class] and use a 32-bit oracle dll?

Comment: As I said, *only* the setting on the EXE project matters.  You can leave the libraries at AnyCPU.

Comment: Ah sorry I misread that, thank you for that bit of information. I now get Could not load file or assembly Oracle.DataAccess so I require a 32-bit DLL for Oracle then.